# Circle Detection on openCV

Tags: opencv

I am compiling the following code in openCV 2.1 and visual studio 2008,

```
        int main()
        {
            Mat src, src_gray;

           /// Read the image
          src = cvLoadImageM("Circle_3.jpg",1);

          if( !src.data )
          {
           cout<<"   "<<"Error!!!!!!!!!!"<<endl;
           return -1; 
          }

          /// Convert it to gray
         cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
            GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

           vector<Vec3f> circles;

      /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
             HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
       /// Draw the circles detected
          for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
         {
               Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
                int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
                        // circle center
             circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
               // circle outline
            circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );

             }

               /// Show your results

            imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );

              waitKey(0);
               return 0;

                     }
```

there are two problems with this code:
                    1.)It's not giving the desired result(builds fine!)
                    2.)It's not taking input quite many a time:(

Looking forward to guidance...

Comment: In the case of input problem it opens a debugger...

Comment: the supposed output of this code is a red cicular frame around the circle,and a green  dot at the circle's center...but it just displays the image!!!

Comment: what do you mean by not taking input? The image cannot load? maybe it's a problem of accessing the file that you give due to wrong name or access privileges.
Also, the Hough transform function is dependent of the parameters, you can make the detection softer or harder, the result always depends on the parameters and your image. For usage you can of course see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

Comment: by "not taking input" I mean that the image does not get loaded(that's what I understood),coz I tried different images,some got loaded while some didn't...@George Aprilis

Comment: It means that you code prints the error message? Look at the use of the loading function [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvLoadImageM) and be sure that you load an acceptable type. Also, you use `1` which is `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`, try to load it immediately as GRAY and check what type your images are; grayscale or color.

Comment: I am mostly loading jpg images...@George Aprilis

Comment: what is the output in the case of not having loaded the picture?

Comment: It opens the debugger!!!@George Aprilis